# Is there a way to use the Visual Studio Configuration Manager to pull configuration files out of an env folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configurationmanager

I use a project structure that has an **env folder with various folders under it for different environments**.  For example, under a web project that has a log4net configuration, the following paths would exist:

> - {project root}\env\dev\log4net.config
> - {project root}\env\qa\log4net.config

**I know that web config transforms are an option, but is there a way to use the Visual Studio configuration manager to pull these files into the {project root} depending on a specified configuration?**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

Comment: +1 for a way to use the configuration directives to facilitate this behavior.  It doesn't quite solve my problem, however...it would work for anything I use the ConfigurationManager class for, but not for things like the log4net.config, which just has to end up in the bin folder.  Really I just want the files copied to the root level on a build.